# Ui-router state with state parameter not recognized on page reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an extremely strange situation with ui-router.  I have a state defined like so:

```
.state('profileQuestion', {
        url: '/profile-questions/:profileQuestionId',
        templateUrl: 'client/users/views/profile-question.ng.html',
        controller: 'profileQuestionCtrl'
 })
```

It works fine and dandy as I navigate through the app.  However, if I go straight to this page, for example `localhost:3000/profile-questions/1`, the app does not recognize the page, and immediately tries to go to the `otherwise` route.

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
```

What's more, it actually goes to `/profile-questions/login` instead of just `/login`!  The controller for profile-questions never gets called.  So in sum, this ui router works fine when I navigate to the page from another, but fails when I load the page by itself.  I should add that if I remove the state parameter options `:profileQuestionId`, the `/profile-questions` route loads correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: This is a server issue, not angular, not UI-Router - https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: Do you config the app to be in html5 mode?

Comment: Yes I did.  I'm using ionic, angular, and meteor, and I believe that was in the angular-meteor tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

As @Radim Kohler and @Joe Lloyd suggested, the issue is that HTML5 mode was turned on.  I see now that the server thinks I am looking for something in the /profile-questions/ directory - which doesn't exist.  To fix this, I just changed it to be a query string parameter like so:

```
.state('profileQuestion', {
        url: '/profile-question?profileQuestionId',
        templateUrl: 'client/users/views/profile-question.ng.html',
        controller: 'profileQuestionCtrl'
 })
```